# In React, How to select multiple items & toggle off on a click away event

Tags: reactjs, toggle, onclicklistener, react-hooks

The scenario is as follows:

- 1) There is a list of items with multiple functionality inside each
    item (i.e. multiple onClick events and the like).
- 2) user can select multiple items, and the background will change color.
- 3) user can toggle the selection 'off' by clicking the item again.
- 4) user can click on the children buttons within the item, and that will not toggle the item's 
    selection.
- 5) If a user has 1 or more selections, and clicks away from the items, then all selections 
    will toggle 'off' (like closing a modal).

I'm using [React Use's UseClickAway Hook](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useClickAway.md) to handle the click away functionality.

The example in the code sandbox works as expected, however, I feel that there a better solution staring at me in the face, and I'm too blind to see it.

I'm unsure if using the variable `CLICKED_INSIDE` is a react anti-pattern, or could cause a major headache in the future. And, having to pass `onNestedClick()` as a prop & invoke in each child function seems a bit repetitive & overkill.

Thanks for taking the time.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/toggle-items-w-click-away-c5sif?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Is there a reason why you <Demo /> component is a functional component and not a class component? You could easily manage this with state.

Comment: It needs to be functional because other code that was omitted for clarity relies on hooks. 
I tried to use `useState()` for the `CLICKED_INSIDE' variable, but it doesn't update quick enough to be used in the `useClickAway()` hook. 

I found a more "react" solution using `useRef()` hook for the `CLICKED_INSIDE` variable